# How to create new organization in Plastic SCM

Tags: unity-game-engine, plasticscm

now im working on a project as UNITY, and use version control tool as a Plastic SCM.
I want to make more organization as needed, is there a way to make more organization in Plastic SCM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- From the Unity Id home page in "Organizations"(https://id.unity.com/en/organizations) click on "Add new"
- From the Unity dashboard (https://dashboard.unity3d.com) create a new project for the new Organization
- Go to the "DevOps" section and to PlasticSCM overview
- Click on "Try for free" and activate a new Plastic SCM subscription for that new Organization.